# ExoPlayer in RecyclerView plays video on scroll down but shows empty when scrolling back up

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, exoplayer

*I've set up a RecyclerView for posts on my home fragment. It handles images using a ViewPager and videos with ExoPlayer. I've set a common ExoPlayer class managing the video playback by passing the video URL based on item position. But ExoPlayer only plays video first time in the list when I scroll down to it. When I scroll back up, the video player displays an empty view instead of the desired video.*

Here is my code

```
In Fragment 

private fun setAdapter() {
    recyclerViewFollowings.apply {
        adapter = homeFollowingPostAdapter
        addOnScrollListener(scrollListener)
    }
}

private val scrollListener = object : RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
    override
    fun onScrolled(recyclerView:RecyclerView, dx: Int, dy: Int) {
        val llm = layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager
        val firstVisibleItem = llm.findFirstVisibleItemPosition()
        ...
        if (firstVisibleItem != lastFirstVisiblePosition) {
            homeFollowingPostAdapter.commonExoPlayer.pausePlayer()
            Handler().postDelayed({
                if (firstVisibleItem < onePageDataList!!.size) {
                    val viewHolder = findViewHolderForAdapterPosition(firstVisibleItem)
                    if (viewHolder is HomeFollowingPostAdapter.ViewHolder) {
                        viewHolder.playStopVideo(firstVisibleItem)
                    }
                }
            }, 3000)
         }
        ...
    }
}
```

In HomeFollowingPostAdapter

```
 class HomeFollowingPostAdapter(var context: Context) :
    AdvanceRecycleViewAdapter<BaseHolder<DataItem>, DataItem>() {

    var commonExoPlayer: CommonExoPlayer = CommonExoPlayer(context)
    val player = commonExoPlayer.getPlayer()
    private var storyUrl: String? = null

    override fun createDataHolder(
        parent: ViewGroup,
        viewType: Int
    ): BaseHolder<DataItem> {
        return ViewHolder(parent.toBinding())
    }

    inner class ViewHolder(private val binding: HomeFollowingPostRowBinding) :
        BaseHolder<DataItem>(binding.root) {

        fun onBindView(followingPost: DataItem) = with(binding) {

            textViewUserName.text =
                layoutPosition.toString() + " " + followingPost.type
            if (items?.get(layoutPosition)?.type == "post") {
                val adapter = ImageSliderAdapter() { adapter, position, action ->
                }
                viewPagerPost.adapter = adapter
                adapter.items = followingPost.file_url as MutableList<FileUrl>?
                viewPagerPost.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                clVideoView.visibility = View.GONE
            } else {
                viewPagerPost.visibility = View.GONE
                clVideoView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageViewPost.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                imageViewPost.setImageWithOptimize(followingPost.file_url?.get(0)?.thumb_url)
              
            }
        }


        fun playStopVideo(firstVisibleItem: Int) {
            if (firstVisibleItem == itemViewType){
                player?.let {
                    
                    //Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed({
                    Log.d("MMM player: ", player.toString())
                    binding.videoViewPost.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    binding.imageViewPost.visibility = View.GONE
                    binding.videoViewPost.player = player
                    if (itemViewType != -1){
                        commonExoPlayer.prepareMedia(items?.get(itemViewType)?.file_url?.get(0)?.post_url.toString()) // Prepare media with the provided URL
                        binding.videoViewPost.player = player
                    }
                    //}, 500)

                }
            }

        }
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return position.toLong()
    }

    override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
        return position
    }

    override fun onBindDataHolder(
        holder: BaseHolder<DataItem>,
        position: Int,
        item: DataItem
    ) {
        when (holder) {
            is ViewHolder -> {
                holder.onBindView(item)
            }
        }
    }

}
```

In ViewHolder

```
inner class ViewHolder(binding: HomeFollowingPostRowBinding) : BaseHolder<DataItem>(binding.root) {
    fun playStopVideo(firstVisibleItem: Int) {
        if (firstVisibleItem == itemViewType) {
            player?.let {
                binding.videoViewPost.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                binding.videoViewPost.player = it
                if (itemViewType != -1) {
                   commonExoPlayer.prepareMedia(items?.get(itemViewType)?.file_url?.get(0)?.post_url.toString())
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

CommonExoPlayer

```
class CommonExoPlayer(context: Context) {
    private var simplePlayer: ExoPlayer? = null

    fun getPlayer(): ExoPlayer? {
        if (simplePlayer == null) {
            prepareVideoPlayer()
        }
        return simplePlayer
    }

    private fun prepareVideoPlayer() {
        simplePlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build()
        ...
    }

    fun prepareMedia(linkUrl: String) {
        pausePlayer()
        ...
        val mediaSource =  ProgressiveMediaSource.Factory(dataSourceFactory).createMediaSource(MediaItem.fromUri(linkUrl))
        simplePlayer!!.setMediaSource(mediaSource)
        simplePlayer?.prepare()
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```

*Expected Behavior:* **The ExoPlayer should play the video associated with the currently visible item in the RecyclerView, regardless of scrolling direction.**

Comment: Please share the onCreateViewHodler and onBindViewHolder code in your homeFollowingPostAdapter.

Comment: ExoPlayer should have some Log if it has error when rendering, did you check the Logcat?

Comment: I have checked Logcat but I didn't find any error.